# Error in parsing JSON data as ORA-40441: JSON syntax error

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I am trying to parse the JSON data into JSON_OBJECT_T in oracle PL/SQL but i am getting error as

> ORA-40441: JSON syntax error

My Oracle version is 12C R2. My code:

```
Declare
VALUE VARCHAR2(30000);
L_DATA_OBJECT   JSON_OBJECT_T;
Begin
VALUE:='{"bookingRefNo":"TAS20200721083517690","bookingStatus":"Waiting for Approval","bookingStatusId":"13","createdDate":"2020-07-21","entryExit":[{"bookingRefNo":"TAS20200721083517690","cargoType":"Goods Transportation","cargoTypeId":10,"entryExitStatus":"Entry","entryExitStatusId":1,"purpose":"Goods Transportation","purposeId":8,"sn":"1"},{"bookingRefNo":"TAS20200721083517690","cargoType":"Goods Transportation","cargoTypeId":10,"entryExitStatus":"Exit","entryExitStatusId":2,"purpose":"Goods Transportation","purposeId":8,"sn":"0"}],"portCode":"10","scheduleFrom":"2020-08-08 01:00 AM","scheduleTo":"2020-08-08 01:59 AM","transportAgentId":"ubce010","transportAgentName":"U??­U??¯  U??§?³U?U?","truckDriverId":"7875533333","truckDriverName":"dgga","truckId":"1234","truckLicNo":"1236699","truckPlateNo":"1204ARA","zoneCode":"G7","zoneScheduleId":"G7101589902849699"}';
L_OBJECT    :=JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE(VALUE);
End
```

The problem is coming for

```
 "transportAgentName":"U??­U??¯  U??§?³U?U?"
```

If i change "U??­U??¯  U??§?³U?U?" to some normal text and numbers then it works perfectly.

Comment: Looks like a character set issue. Check your database character set and your client settings, and find out what the real value for that attribute should be.

Comment: This is JSON response i am getting from external API. I can not ask them to change the way data is given. I need to strip out these unwanted characters from the VALUE.

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue on Oracle 18c. Copy/pasting (and fixing `L_OBJECT` to be `L_DATA_OBJECT`) then your code works [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6a2c65bf3b7d53a6aa345235fc1a81d0). However, your code appears to have changed the data from a unicode value to ASCII so it may be that we don't have the correct data to work with.

Comment: Its not working with me even if i changed to L_DATA_OBJECT. how can i remove these characters from VALUE before parsing?

Comment: What character set are you using to retrieve data from the API, and what character set is it working in? Ideally you'd be using UTF-8 all the way through. Have you looked at the value they they think they're sending you and how it's expected to be interpreted? Throwing away part of the data you get probably isn't the right action.

Comment: My Oracle version is 12C R2

Comment: yes i am using charset=utf-8 when adding header

Comment: Could you try using [convert](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620) before parsing and check then ?